# How do I send multiple payloads at once to SendGrid's API in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, post, sendgrid

From following their [API docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Reseller_API/customer_management.html#-Update-Customer-Password), the curl command to interact with their API should look something like this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sendgrid.com/apiv2/reseller.manage.json \
-d api_user=reseller@company.com \
-d api_key=XXXXXXXX \
-d user=reseller_customer@company.com \
-d password=customernewpassword \
-d confirm_password=customernewpassword \
-d method=password
```

How do I write that in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the RestClient gem. It makes it easy to send requests like this.
https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

Comment: Is this the function I need? `RestClient.post '/data', {:foo => 'bar', :multipart => true}` The README is not real clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SendGrid API by using ruby to curl the url. If you aren't constrained to using curl, you should take a look at the official ruby gem though https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby

Comment: Unfortunately, the gem only utilizes their Web API. I need to use their Reseller API.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sendgrid SMTP API, there are code examples in their docs; see here for example, https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/ruby.html.